# What is the difference between nginx daemon on/off option?

Tags: nginx, webserver, daemon, docker

This is my first web-server administration experience and I want to build docker container which uses nginx as a web-server. In all docker tutorial `daemon off;` option is put into main `.conf` file but explanation about it is omitted.

I search on the internet about it and I don't understand what is the difference between `daemon on;` and `daemon off;` options. Some people mentioned that `daemon off;` is for production, why?

Can you explain, what is the difference between this two options, and why I should use `daemon off;` on production?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

For normal production (on a server), use the default `daemon on;` directive so the Nginx server will start in the background. In this way Nginx and other services are running and talking to each other. One server runs many services.

For **Docker containers** (or for debugging), the `daemon off;` directive tells Nginx to stay in the foreground.  For containers this is useful as best practice is for one container = one process. One server (container) has only one service.

Setting `daemon off;` is also useful if there's a 3rd party tool like [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) controlling your services.  Supervisor lets you stop/start/get status for bunches of services at once.

I use `daemon off;` for tweaking my Nginx config, then cleanly killing the service and restarting it.  This lets me test configurations rapidly. When done I use the default `daemon on;`.

Comment: How do you reload dynamically nginx configurated as "daemon off" on docker?

Comment: This seems like the correct answer, and it should be tick marked.

Comment: @kemalatila not sure but I guess you could rely on nginx signals by running `nginx -s` then using one of the signals stated [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/basic-functionality/runtime-control/)

Answer (score 25):

As mentioned in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861300/how-to-run-nginx-within-docker-container-without-halting), it appears that "that initial process immediately spawns a master nginx process and some workers, and then quits. Since Docker is only watching the PID of the original command, the container then halts."

Regarding the [`daemon off` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#daemon), it appears that it was originally intended for nginx code development, though is safe for production post version 1.0.9, per the [FAQ](http://nginx.org/en/docs/faq/daemon_master_process_off.html).