# What is the difference between the presence and absence of the -g option in nginx?

Tags: nginx, command-line-arguments

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debug_symbol

When running nginx on the docker, I was curious about -g option.

```
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Searching wikipedia, it is so hard for me.

`-g` option, can I use new commands? or Is there any other difference?

Plz, Tell me. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-g` option of NGINX is used for specifying NGINX flags, `daemon off` in this case.
It has nothing to do with GCC's `-g` option or the mentioned Wikipedia link.

For NGINX command line options, see:

- https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/commandline/

For explanation about the `daemon off` setting:

- [What is the difference between nginx daemon on/off option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970711/what-is-the-difference-between-nginx-daemon-on-off-option)