# what does nginx command do inside the container?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I have a pod with nginx image, but it also has the command "nginx".

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
name: nx
spec:
containers:

- name: nginx
  image: nginx
  command: ["nginx"] #what does this do? it's not bin/sh -c
  args: ["-g", "daemon off;", "-q"]
  ports:

  - containerPort: 80

-g daemon off is means 'nginx runs in quiet mode.

But what is 'nginx' cmd actually? Does it mean it says enter the actual web-server nginx?

Comment: https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/search?l=dockerfile got some good explanation

Answer (score 1):

- `nginx` : Yes , this command starts nginx server.[Nginx command line options](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/commandline/)
- `daemon off`  option for `nginx` command runs nginx in foreground instead of running it as a system daemon (background process).[difference between daemon off and daemon on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970711/what-is-the-difference-between-nginx-daemon-on-off-option#:%7E:text=For%20Docker%20containers%20(or%20for,container)%20has%20only%20one%20service.)

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to run nginx in a docker container, when you set `nginx -g 'daemon off;` you run as a background process as mentioned before, in addition that you can interact with the container terminal.