# Running Nginx on Docker

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, docker

I'm learning how to build Docker images from Dockerfiles. Here's my current Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx
CMD ["/usr/sbin/nginx"]
```

I can build this image, run it, and connect to the container with `docker run -t -i -p 80:80 mytestimage /bin/bash/`. Then, I can run `nginx` and connect to the "hello world" page from a web browser.

But I can't get Nginx to run as a daemon (without manually starting it from the container's shell). I've tried `docker run -d -p 80:80 mytestimage`, but `docker ps` is empty. What am I doing wrong? I've been looking at the [official Nginx Dockerfile](https://github.com/dockerfile/nginx/blob/master/Dockerfile), but I'm not sure which parts I need to add to my own Dockerfile.

Comment: check this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861300/how-to-run-nginx-within-docker-container-without-halting

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you need to add following in Dockerfile

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

and the docker container can be run using command : docker run -d -p 8980:80 test-nginx

above port 8980 just an example, this is configured from Dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that nginx doesn't run in the foreground so every time your container executes the `CMD` directive, it returns and then the container exits.

You need to add the following to your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` at the top

```
daemon off;
```

Then you can just run your container like this:

```
docker run -ti -p 80:80 mytestimage
```

Answer (score 0):

You must execute nginx on startup. Here is how you do it. add CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"] inside dockerFile.

Full guide: [How to setup PHP 8, NGINX and php-fpm docker](https://www.reviewcurious.com/how-to-setup-php-8-nginx-php-fpm-and-alpine-with-docker/)